# jquery mobile update without rewriting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this little code that works great except one thing: If i have my collapsible-set expanded, it will collapse back every 5 seconds because i set `setTimeout(loadPage,5000)`. My question is: How to construct this little code without rewriting, so even if it's expanded it will update without collapsing . . .

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
    var globalVar = {};

    function loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://jsbin.com/wulol/2.js",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                globalVar = data;
            }
        });
    }

    function loadPage() {
        var items = '';
        $.each(globalVar, function (index, item) {
            items += "<div data-role='collapsible' id='" + item.id + "'>";
            items += "<h3>";
            items += "<div class='ui-grid-c'>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-a'>" + item.airline + "</div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-b'>" + item.number + "</div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-c'>" + item.people + "</div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-d'>" + item.time + "</div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-a'></div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-b'></div>";
            items += "<div class='ui-block-c'></div>";
            items += "</div>";
            items += "</h3>";
            items += "<p><input type='button' value='Button'></p>";
            items += "</div>";
        });
        $("#result").html(items);
        $("#result").trigger('create');
        setTimeout(loadPage, 5000);

    }

    function ignite() {
        loadData();
        loadPage();
    }
    window.onload = ignite;
});
```

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rikuk/2/edit?js,output) 
I really need your help, people of Earth ! ! !

Comment: You need to compare divs, if exist ignore it, if not append it on $("#result")

Comment: Aimadnet, could you please, somehow, be a little more specific . . . I mean, an example would save my life :) Thanks
p.s. I added a working DEMO so you can see what i'm talking about.

Comment: @user3115243 have u tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use append() instead of html(), but before you need to check if the item already exist in #result or not.

DEMO : http://jsbin.com/yabopuzu/1/edit

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    var globalVar = {};
    function loadData(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://jsbin.com/wulol/2.js",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            globalVar = data;
            }
        });
    }
    function loadPage(){
        var items='';
        $.each(globalVar,function(index,item)
        {
            if ($("#result #item"+item.id).size()==0)
            {
                items+= "<div data-role='collapsible' id='item"+item.id+"'>";
                items+= "<h3>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-grid-c'>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-a'>"+item.airline+"</div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-b'>"+item.number+"</div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-c'>"+item.people+"</div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-d'>"+item.time+"</div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-a'></div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-b'></div>";
                items+= "<div class='ui-block-c'></div>";
                items+= "</div>";
                items+= "</h3>";
                items+= "<p><input type='button' value='Button'></p>";
                items+= "</div>";
            }
        });
        $("#result").append(items);
        $("#result").trigger('create');
        setTimeout(loadPage,5000);
    }
    function ignite(){
        loadData();
        loadPage();
    }
    window.onload = ignite;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `data-collapsed="false"` attribute ot your wrapper.

Change:

```
items+= "<div data-role='collapsible' id='item"+item.id+"'>";
```

To:

```
items+= "<div data-collapsed="false" data-role='collapsible' id='item"+item.id+"'>";
```

See the [Docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/collapsibles/#Setofindividualcollapsibles)